# RHTML displaying HTML tags on output

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, view, ruby-on-rails-3, rhtml

I have an RHTML view in Rails, where the output is coming from my MongoDB collection. The data is outputted correctly using an iteration block, but whenever I try and have HTML tags in my database, they are not rendered in the HTML output, instead they are just displayed.

```
<%
 @posts.find().each do |post|
%>
 <h1><%=post["name"]%></h1>
 <p><%=post["body"] %></p>
 <p><%=post["timestamp"]%></p>
<%
 end
%>
```

But, for instance, if I had

```
<p>Test</p>
```

In my database, the tags would be rendered, instead of being printed.

Comment: You shouldn't need the `find()` after @posts

Comment: if @posts is a collection object he does

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a security precaution that is now built into Rails 3. It prevents XSS (cross-site scripting) issues.

If you add `raw` you'll get the output you want.

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %> 
 <h1><%=raw post["name"]%></h1> 
 <p><%=raw post["body"] %></p> 
 <p><%=raw post["timestamp"]%></p> 
<% end %>
```

However, if you are storing user-created arbitrary HTML, I don't recommend you do this unless you are sanitizing the input prior to storing it in the database.

Edit:

Another option: Using the [`sanitize` helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html) in place of `raw`, e.g. `<%=sanitize post["name"], :tags => "p" %>` to allow `<p>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

Apart from `raw` and `.html_safe`, which give 100% trust to the user's input, you could also use `sanitize` to restrict only a number of tags that allowed.

<%= sanitize post["name"] $>

For the details, see: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/SanitizeHelper.html

Comment: Good point about sanitize. +1 to you and I've updated my answer.